# Empty all log files in a directory

Tags: files, logs

I recently came across [this page](https://www.tecmint.com/empty-delete-file-content-linux/) that indicates how to empty a file. How can I do it for all files in a given subfolder ?

For instance, by using `> file.log` to empty a file ?

I basically want to create a VM instance image, and I'd like to clear existing log files so when the template is used it starts fresh without lingering data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
for i in /var/log/*; do
    > "$i"
done
```

If you want to avoid the error messages for the directories, include a test.

```
for i in /var/log/*; do
    test -f "$i" && > "$i"
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure by what you meant by "error messages for the directories", but If I run your original command in an empty directory it actually creates a file named `*`

Comment: Yes, if you run it in an empty directory it actually creates a file named `*`, but then obviously there is no need for it. It is also possible to include a test against the directory being empty, and in fact the second version doesn't create a file `*`. What I meant is if the directory is not empty, but contains sub directories, you will get an error message for each sub directory with the first command. You can ignore that message, but if you use a script, then use the second command.

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob` will help the empty-directory scenario

Comment: Hey, how can I run this command with sudo ?

Comment: You can either place the commands in a file and run that file, or run it as one command: `sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/log/*; do test -f "$i" && > "$i"; done`.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, does not work. There is just a `>` symbol which waits for more input.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, in a single command, would be [`truncate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate):

```
truncate -s /var/log/*
```

The above will emit errors for any subdirectories of /var/log, though:

> truncate: cannot open '/var/log/subdir' for writing: Is a directory

... which you can silence by dropping stderr:

```
truncate -s /var/log/* 2>/dev/null
```

If there are no files or directories, then you have to beware of the current `nullglob` shell option. By default, it is turned off:

```
$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        off
```

... which will leave the `*` unexpanded, and thus `truncate` will create a file named `*`. You can avoid this in two ways:

1. set nullglob: `shopt -s nullglob` before running `truncate`. You will then (if you haven't dropped stderr) see an error:

   > truncate: missing file operand
2. tell `truncate` not to create missing files: `truncate --no-create -s 0 /var/log/*`